# Writing a Python word game

Tags: python

I want to write a program that takes two words per round (number of round given by user) and print "qualified" if the last letter of first word equals to the first letter of second word, print "duplicate word error" if both words are the same and print "not qualified" if none of the above is correct.

```
n = int(input())

for i in range(n):
    w1 = input()
    w2 = input()
    
    if (w1[-1]) == (w2[0]):
        print("qualified")
    elif (w1) == (w2):
        print("duplicate word error")
    else:
        print("not qualified")
```

The result when n = 2 is:

```
2
pet
tea
qualified
world
window
not qualified
```

but I want to see this result:

```
2
pet
tea
world
window
qualified
not qualified
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Personally, I think your current output is better. You do have answers already on how to fix it so it works the way you want it. Right now imagine I've decided to do 100 rounds. If you keep the result till the end I will end up with 200 words and 100 results after printing and will need to find out what result is for what pair of words. Consider this before changes.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you need, is to remember some information about each round, and then finally print it whole at the end.

One of many possibilities, is to store the result of each round in a list, and then nicely print it:

```
n = int(input())

rounds_results = []
for i in range(n):
    w1 = input()
    w2 = input()
    
    if (w1[-1]) == (w2[0]):
        rounds_results.append("qualified")
    elif (w1) == (w2):
        rounds_results.append("duplicate word error")
    else:
        rounds_results.append("not qualified")

for result in rounds_results:
    print(result)
```

Comment: if i want to print the words with odd length ( the middle letter should be in this list 
 [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n] ) how can i add this code to the above code....

Comment: if i want to print the words with odd length ( the middle letter should be in this list 
 [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n] ) how can i add this code to the above code.... @AlexeyLarionov

Comment: @Sina I suggest you to create another question, because the other learners might find your question through Google. The idea is to use `len(w)` function to get a length of a string, then to check even/odd you can use modulo operator `x % 2`, which gives a remainder of division of `x` by 2 (it will be 0 for even numbers and 1 for odd). About the letters, that's tricky

Comment: It's tricky, because would use `in` operator, which checks if something is inside an iterator. E.g. `'c' in ['a', 'b']` checks, if a letter 'c' is among those stored in the list `['a', 'b']`, in this case it's `False`

Answer (score 0):

All of your code is correct (well done!) but you're printing the result straightaway - save it to a list and then print it later. Like so:

```
n = int(input())
outputsList = []

for i in range(n):
    w1 = input()
    w2 = input()
    if (w1[-1]) == (w2[0]):
        outputsList.append("qualified")
    elif (w1) == (w2):
        outputsList.append("duplicate word error")
    else:
        outputsList.append("not qualified")

for result in outputsList:
    print(result)
```

Comment: Nice try, but this will save only the last result, because `if` is placed outside of the loop. It also clears the list on each iteration

Comment: okay ill fix it done